# I am able to send enquires from website but not getting received in mailbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, email

I've created a landing HTML page for my client with enquiry form. The website is designed in Wordpress and I'hv designed a landing page in html and for mailing used php code.

The website details are 
website- http://inspaceinterior.com/
and my designed landing page link is
  website- http://inspaceinterior.com/inspacelanding

The problem is that when I submit the enquiry its not received in mail while on submitting message show "your message has been sent".

The landing page html php script all coding are correct because this page successfully run on other domains and I receive all mails from other domain.

Is there anyone who can tell me what seems to be the problem?
I am uploading all files of this landing page through filezilla in wordpress site or other site.

Comment: Where is your code example for anyone to see where you might be going wrong?

Comment: Please read this page carefully before asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your link shouldn't be necessary.